# Why does my tableview not display anything?

Tags: swift

Currently I have tried setting up a json api to return all of a user's follower's usernames. I'm having an issue where if I try and add a breakpoint at the start of a tableview function (and a dispatch queue) they don't work, and I have no idea why. All of my other breakpoints work. Anyways, what I want to accomplish here is to return each user's follower's username into a different cell. I have tried different solutions from the *internet* but none of them worked.I have tried testing the code below and all the cells were empty. Here is some of my code for anyone that could possibly figure out what in tarnation I'm doing wrong.

**view controller**

```
import UIKit

class FollowerListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return followers.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        parseFollowers() // Second breakpoint
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
        tableView.dataSource = self;
        let follower = followers[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel!.text = follower.username
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        return cell

    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        parseFollowers()
    }
    struct Root: Codable {
        let followers : FollowerData
    }
    struct FollowerData: Codable {
        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case username = "username"
        }
        let username : String
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var followers = [FollowerData]()
    func parseFollowers() {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
            let url =  URL(string: "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/profiles/1.json")
            let jsonData = NSData(contentsOf: url!)
            let output = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: jsonData! as Data)
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            showNoResponseFromServer()
            return
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {  // Second breakpoint
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    func showNoResponseFromServer() {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "No response from server. Try again later.", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

**The json repsonse from the server**

```
{
    "username": "test1",
    "followers": [
        {
            "username": "test2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: where are you adding values i followers array ?

Answer (score 1):

Move this line

```
tableView.dataSource = self
```

to `viewDidLoad` and change the datasource array

```
let output = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: jsonData! as Data)
self.followers = output.followers
```

and don't use `let jsonData = NSData(contentsOf: url!)` as it blocks the main thread use `Alamofire` or `URLsession`